# What is a partly hollow cylinder?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I am given inner radius is 2 and outer radius is 3. Is it just a cylinder with a cylinder cut out the whole way through?

Comment: That's what I would assume.

Comment: Mh, doesn't *partly* contradict *whole way through* ? Aren't you given other information ?